# How we can prove that $a_n=\sum _{k=1}^nf\left(k\right)-\int _0^n f(t)\:dt$ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

We have $f:\left(-1,\infty \right)\:\rightarrow \:R,\:f\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ and we need to prove that:

$a_n=\sum _{k=1}^nf\left(k\right)-\int _0^n\:f\left(x\right)dx$ is convergent.Maybe, in this case, we can use MVT ?

Comment: Presumably $\int_0^n$ is supposed to denote $\int_0^n f(t)\,dt$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is increasing then

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left( \underbrace{f(k)-\int_{k-1}^k f(x)dx}_{\ge0}\right)$$
so $(a_n)$ is increasing
and 
$$f(k)-\int_{k-1}^k f(x)dx=\int_{k-1}^k (f(k)-f(x))dx\le f(k)-f(k-1)$$
so by telescoping we get

$$a_n\le f(n)-f(0)$$
so if $f$ has a finite limit at $+\infty$ then $a_n$ is bounded above and then it's convergent.

Comment: in my book they say f is decreasing

Comment: The function $x\mapsto \frac x{x+1}$ is increasing but if you replace $f$ by $-f$ and then $a_n$ by $-a_n$ the function is decreasing and by a similar proof we get the result again.

Answer (score 0):

Write $\frac{x}{x+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{x+1}$ and realize the problem reduces to $f=-1/(x+1)$.

Now $$0 \leq -\frac{1}{1+k} + \int_{k-1}^k \frac{1}{1+x} \leq \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1},$$
which can be shown by using the montonicity of $1/(1+x)$.

But the above series is $O(1/k^2)$ and converges, so by the comparison test, the series we are interested in converges.

Comment: why you put in module?

Comment: Absolute value? I just took it out with some changes. The point is, you got to be careful with your signs and make sure you have something positive.